# How to generate a view of pairs from an array?

Tags: c++, boost, range-v3, boost-range

I have a C array of `int`s, and its size, i.e. `int* arr, unsigned size`. I want to have something like a view from it, which will have pairs of `int`s as elements.

To clarify, the task is: I receive an array like `[1,2,3,4]` and I want a view, which will be something like `[(1,2),(3,4)]`.

Is there any convenient way to transform array in such a way via boost, or maybe, ranges (std::ranges, or range-v3)?

Comment: `ranges::v3::view::chunk(2)` creates a range of range(of size 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may create a range of range of size 2 with `ranges::v3::view::chunk(2)`

or create a tuple:

```
auto r = ranges::view::counted(p, size);
auto even = r | ranges::view::stride(2);
auto odd = r | ranges::view::drop(1) | ranges::view::stride(2);
auto pairs = ranges::view::zip(even, odd);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f98c8e19e4260410)

Answer (score 2):

You can use range-v3, it has `span` to view a raw array, and `view::chunk` to group adjacent elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/chunk.hpp>
#include <range/v3/span.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>

namespace view = ranges::view;

int main() {
    int vec[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    ranges::span<int> s(vec, sizeof(vec)/sizeof(vec[0]));

    ranges::for_each(s | view::chunk(2), [] (auto chunk) {
                std::pair pr{chunk.at(0), chunk.at(1)};

                std::cout << pr.first << " " << pr.second << "\n";
            });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lbxVxgyv7PysC7mU)